# What would be causing so much bandwidth usage if there are no large files?

Tags: html, web-hosting, html5, bandwidth

I'm pretty new to web design/coding so I'm sorry if this question has an obvious answer I've overlooked. I'm currently working on a website for a small company (from scratch/no CMS) and am basing it off of the [HTML5reset](http://html5reset.org/) to get used to some of that stuff.

I FTPd an early version of the site to the server (hosted by [Netix](http://netix.ca/)) for the client to OK. The next day I got a call from the client saying that the netix had called him to tell him that his site was taking up something like 10GB of bandwidth on the server. From what I can see the site is no bigger than 10MB. I called netix to try and figure it out with them. I was informed that there is some sort of 'bandwidth leakage' in my code, but couldn't get any more information.

I'm at a total loss. I don't understand this at all and don't even know where to begin when it comes to diagnosing the problem. I can't even log in to the control panel on the site as I get a 509 Bandwidth Limit Exceeded error.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Do you have any visitor stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to access the backend to have that answer, so you can start by asking it to the hosting company.

**If your host has a log analyser** like AwStats, just look at it, as it provides bandwidth spending data. An example of a AWS report:

http://www.nltechno.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=destailleur.fr

**If they don't have a log analyzer** they have to provide you with information that allows a knowledgeable person to fix the problem. Just saying that there's some sort of bandwidth leakage in your code is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody could be placing images on their own site by directly linking to the images on your site.